# How to make order by clause dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, sql-order-by

I am using SQL Server 2008, I want sorted data based on input column name and sort order (asc/ desc).How to make below query dynamic?

```
DECLARE @iColumnName VARCHAR(24);
DECLARE @iSortOrder VARCHAR(10);

SET @iColumnName = 'ReceiptLocation'; -- ReceiptLocation/DeliverLocation/NominationNbr
SET @iSortOrder = 'DESC'; -- DESC / ASC

SELECT sum(NominationNbr)
    ,sum(ReceiptLocation)
    ,sum(DeliverLocation)
FROM tables
GROUP BY NominationNbr
    ,ReceiptLocation
    ,DeliverLocation
ORDER BY CASE @iColumnName
        WHEN 'ReceiptLocation'
            THEN ReceiptLocation
        WHEN 'DeliverLocation'
            THEN DeliverLocation
        ELSE NominationNbr
        END   

        CASE @iSortOrder
        WHEN 'DESC'
            THEN DESC
        ELSE ASC
        END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the two.  I would suggest this rather clunky code:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @iColumnName = 'ReceiptLocation' AND @iSortOrder = 'DESC'
               THEN ReceiptLocation
          END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN @iColumnName = 'ReceiptLocation' 
               THEN ReceiptLocation
          END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN @iColumnName = 'DeliverLocation' AND @iSortOrder = 'DESC'
               THEN DeliverLocation
          END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN @iColumnName = 'DeliverLocation' 
               THEN DeliverLocation
          END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN @iSortOrder = 'DESC'
               THEN NominationNbr
          END) DESC,
         NominationNbr ASC
```

Each `CASE` statement is a separate order key.  However, the values are `NULL` if they do not match, so the key doesn't do anything with no match.

You can also implement this using dynamic SQL.  That can be more effective if you have a simple query and indexes that can be used for the `ORDER BY`.